# Wireless issue in Raspi Pi Octoprint

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, wireless

Why does my raspberry pi desktop wireless icon indicate "No wireless interfaces found". And then another window opens and it says "eth0:configured 192.168.1.102/24 wlan0 not associated"

Comment: have you configured wifi?

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/111766/edit) your question and add the output of these two commands on the commandline to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.